# Combine SQL rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a SQL Server question

I have 3 records with data: (the fields filled with dots are empty!)

```
NAME   | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 
blabla | .      | b      | . 
blabla | a      | .      | .
blabla | .      | .      | c
```

Now I want the output to show just one row like this:

```
blabla | a | b | c
```

I'm not sure if it has to be a Case or Group or what else

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use aggregate function for example `max`

```
select name,max(FIELD1) as FIELD1, max(FIELD2) as FIELD2, max(FIELD3) as FIELD3
from tab
group by name
```

Comment: Ok i believe this would work except for the fact that i have inner joins. so now its complaning that field DATA.PARTDESC Invalid because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause

Comment: @Proxx You should add `DATA.PARTDESC` to group by clause

Comment: beat everyone in speed